# how to pause(wait) foreach loop in jQuery until function returns the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

```
$(document).on('click', '#exportDashboardsToReport', function (e) {
checkedValues.forEach(element => {
            if (element.includes("-")) {
                data = element.split('-');
                data.forEach(item => {
                    if (item.substr(0, 1) == "c") {
                        customerId = item.replace("c_", "");                       
                        Customers=customerId;                      
                    } else {
                        Locations =item ;
                    }                                      
                });
                replacePlaceholder(Customers, Locations, function(){
                    addReplaceHolderToFile(Customers, Locations);
                });
                
            }}            
        });
```

While running this code , network pane shows

replacePlaceholder
replacePlaceholder
replacePlaceholder
replacePlaceholder

That means replacePlaceholder() is callled 4 times in one go. But I want foreach loop to wait until   replacePlaceholder() completes its task. Function replacePlaceholder() and addReplaceHolderToFile() has ajax which runs asynchronously. So the sequence must be like this:
run foreach > call replacePlaceholder > wait replacePlaceholder()to complete task > then continue foreach.

Comment: If replacePlaceholder is an asynchronous function, maybe try adding `await` in front of it.

Comment: @NathanMills given that it takes a callback, it's extremely unlikely that `replacePlaceholder` returns a promise. Most asynchronous functions do one or the other. Using `await` only really works with promises.

Comment: Dont use forEach then, use a for loop and async/await